# How to stop HTML5 Audio from playing

Tags: html, audio, attributes, html5-audio

I have flipbook style script that allows people to flip pages and each page has audio embedded. Audio is set to auto play. However, when flipbook is loaded, it plays audio from every single page over another.

Is there a way to control that using following event attributes?

onpageshow
onpagehide

Following is audio code in each of the page with different sound for each page.

```
    <audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="mpthreetest.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" autoplay="true">
</audio>
```

I would like audio for each page to star when visitor navigates to that page then stop when visitor navigates away from that page.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Give an id for the audio

```
 var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");

    function playAud() {
        audio.play();
    }

    function pauseAud() {
        audio.pause();
    }
```

When the event happens call these functions and you will be able to control the audio

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have no programming background but I will try.

Comment: Is there any way you can help me with actual code for the page? I have no idea what I am doing. Thanks.

Comment: Sure could you please share  the code or upload  to https://jsfiddle.net/
and if you liked it please up-vote and mark as answer

Comment: I am not sure what to share...it's flipbook plugin for Wordpress.